# How to set default major mode in directory-local file?

Tags: emacs

for some complex reason, I would like to open files in certain directory (can have any name, no extension) in C mode, and I don't want to modify them for Emacs (file-local variables are out). I am struggling with Emacs to do it, however. I tried to put this into my dir-locals.el:

```
((nil . ((major-mode . c-mode))))
```

Although the `major-mode` variable is indeed overridden to `c-mode` when I open file from that directory, the C mode is not enabled on the buffer. What's going on and how do I make it apply?

Alternatively, I could add to the `auto-mode-alist` just for this directory, but I don't know how to do that via directory locals.

Also, is there some easy way to cause execution of code from dir-locals.el? I know it's unsafe, but it could even be the code that is in config - the point is to call it only when variables from dir-locals are processed (opening a file).

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In `.dir-locals.el` you can only set variables to a certain value. What your code does is set the `major-mode` variable to the `c-mode` value. However, this is not the way a mode is activated. To activate it you need to call the function `c-mode`. There is a special variable that you can set in `.dir-locals.el` to run a function: `eval`.

Therefore, the following code works:

```
((nil . ((eval . (c-mode)))))
```

Comment: Thanks. I missed the special local-file variables in the manual, and there is no mention that they also work as directory-local or any examples.

Comment: It is written the other way around but not clearly. It says that the directory local variables are treated like file variables.

Answer (score 14):

Apart from `eval`, there is also another special variable named `mode` which can help you. It is the same variable used by file-local variables. You could also write:

```
((nil . ((mode . c))))
```

Answer (score 2):

i can't answer your first question (and in fact, will like to hear the answer for that myself) but fir the `auto-mode-alist` you can have

```
(setq auto-mode-alist (cons '("<your dir path here>\." . c-mode) auto-mode-alist))`
```

this should give you the result you want

Comment: Thanks, I could do that to solve that problem, although I would like to do something like that from directory local and not from my global config.

Comment: hmmm, how about adding a hook to check the location? besides, as i previously said - i would also want to know the major mode solution...